# What causes this error? - Server error: This schedule may only be modified using the SharePoint forms?

Tags: list, custom-form

I have a list which has a bunch of aspx pages in the root of the list, along with the standard New, Edit, Display forms.  I am not able to save any of these, I recieve the error noted in the Title.  I receive the same error if I try to make a copy of a file using "Copy/Paste" as well as get the error when I try to create a New page in the list.  I believe that this list was created as a custom solution prior to my arrival, but I do not have any clear documentation.

We are guessing this has to do with how this solution was implemented, but I am wondering if there is some way within SharePoint Designer of STSADM that we can "unlock" this so that we can work with the pages and list the same way we can with other lists.

If I am not clear, please let me know, as I would certainly like to understand this better.

Thanks,